# Trying to create a DOM element using Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to create a DOM element inside of an infobox using the Google Maps API, but where I expect to find my element, the browser isn't rendering the element, but plain text about the object. I suspect this has something to do with the way I'm mixing JS and HTML, because if I *just* include the Javascript (with no HTML) the element displays without trouble.

My content variable for the infobox looks something like this:

```
var content = '<strong>Title</strong>' + document.createElement('button');
```

The rendered content looks like this:

```
Title [object HTMLButtonElement]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I suspect this has something to do with the way I'm mixing JS and HTML

Exactly.

```
var content = '<strong>Title</strong>' + document.createElement('button');
```

Your variable here gets assigned a string value first – and then you try to append something to it using the `+` operator, which stands for string concatenation in this context. Since an HTML element is something “imaginary” here, it has to be converted to a string to be able to perform the operation. And when you implicitly “cast” an HTML element to a string, a browser will make that something like `[object HTMLButtonElement]` (the exact text can differ a little bit between different browsers).

Either create all elements using DOM methods (createElement for `strong`, and createTextNode for the text content inside it) – or use `innerHTML`, if that’s possible in your context.